# How to transform ActiveRecord attributes to/from the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, hook, transform

## Question

Is there a built-in API, 3rd party Gem, or common paradigm for applying transformations on data to and from the database in a Rails application?

*Note: I am not looking for helpers, view models, or the standard `before`/`after` ActiveRecord hooks. I need to be able to silently mutate data "underneath" the usual hooks such that the mechanism is decoupled/hidden/unknown to the rest of the application.*

In other words, I'm looking to insert a shim into ActiveRecord somewhere beneath the normal hooks, and somewhere above the database adapter on a per-attribute basis that will allow me to transparently munge the data, like a serializer for the database adapter.

### Trivial Example

```
$ rails new test-app
$ cd test-app
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec rails g scaffold vehicle make model year:integer color
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

In `app/models/vehicle.rb`, something like:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  magic_shim :color, in: :color_upcase, out: :color_downcase

  private
    # Returns a modified value for storage but does not change the
    # attribute value in the ActiveRecord object.
    def color_upcase
      self.color.upcase
    end

    # Accepts the stored value and returns an inversely modified version
    # to be used by the ActiveRecord attribute.
    def color_downcase(stored)
      stored.downcase
    end
end
```

In the rails console (note the capitalization of "Red"):

```
irb> truck = Vehicle.create make: "Ford", model: "F150", year: 2015, color: "Red"
```

In the rails database (color was upcased before storage):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM `vehicles`;
1|Ford|F150|2015|RED|2015-06-24 16:07:33.176769|2015-06-24 16:07:33.176769
```

And back to the console (the app sees a downcased version):

```
irb> truck = Vehicle.find 1
irb> truck.color
=> red
```

Comment: What's wrong with overriding default accessors? (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Overwriting+default+accessors)

Comment: Only that the transformation could be relatively complex, and so would have to be performed on every access of the attributes, rather than just on queries. I suppose I could pursue default accessor overrides and use some sort of caching, but I'd worry about unintended edge cases (think dirty checks, etc).

Comment: ... but now that you've caused me to think about that in depth, I suppose it would only have to be transformed when the attribute is changed, which is much less of an issue.

Comment: @dimuch Post an answer and I'll accept; you've helped me duck out why accessor overriding *is* the right solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moved from comments to answer)

In this case overriding default accessors can solve the problem.
More info and implementation code sample: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Overwriting+default+accessors